# I am building a Count Down Timer app, that starts on pushing the button. The app crashes on pressing the button

Tags: java, final, countdowntimer

On clicking the button the app gets crashed displaying "Unfortunately, zm(app name) has stopped".

The IDE did not show any error.

I tried running this in 2 different devices but it didn't work.

Removing the final keyword shows an error.

**ActivityMain.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView timer_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);

        start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) { //setting time for 30 sec
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long l) {
                        timer_text.setText((int) (l/1000)); //updating by reducing 1 second
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        timer_text.setText(R.string.done); //string that shows completion

                    }
                }.start();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="259dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:text="Press the button to start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.444" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a type mismatch.

You are doing:

```
timer_text.setText((int) (l / 1000));
```

But that mean that you are actually using the `TextView.setText(int resId)` method, not the `setText(String text)` method. Causing it to crash because there is no resource id with your calcul.

A simple solution would be:

```
timer_text.setText(String.valueOf(l / 1000));
```

#### Moreover

- Your code is a bit hard to read, you seems to have pasted multiple time our code.
- You should not be using lower_snake_case as variable name, but lowerCamelCase instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the onCreate Method twice? And also you forgot a '}' in your first onCreate Method, so it should be:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

instead of:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

If it's not working, try delete the first onCreate Method.